# SSL trusted for local web server is possible?

Tags: security, ssl, https

I have local server in my home, which runs website, which provides some service, thanks the use of PHP. Right now I'm using the HTTP protocol, which doesn't not provide security, due to the clear-text (the is a authentication service with username and password to access the protected page). I want to upgrade to HTTPS and of course I need to use the SSL. I know what is, so I know the differences between a self-certificate, and the one issued by a company. There are different kind of class. Because I don't want that my users/friends are alerted by the browser that the SSL certificate isn't trusted, I'm asking if there is some free trusted certificate for a non-domain web server (I use my static IP to let the user access the website). In case I bought a domain (it is very cheaper), can I have a free trusted certificate from someone ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding SSL certificates for an IP address, see the linked SO thread: [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name)

If you register a domain name for your site, then you can obtain a free SSL certificate from StartSSL (https://www.startssl.com/?app=1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In case I bought the domain, will the user get this alert http://www.turnkeylinux.org/files/images/ssl_error.jpg ?

Comment: No, they will not see the error if the SSL certificate is set up correctly for the site.