# Tomcat https answers by hostname, but not by IP

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

Tomcat 7.0.67, RHEL 6.7.  I have a tomcat app that is deployed and listening on port 6443 for https traffic.

tomcat answers fine by request URLS of the form https://hostname:port/rest of URL/etc.  However, it does not answer on https://IP Number:port/rest of URL/etc EXCEPT for tests I run from the server itself.

```
[myuser@myhost ~]$  curl -vk https://IP NUMBER:6443/<rest ofURL>
* About to connect() to IP NUMBER port 6443 (#0)
*   Trying IP NUMBER... connected
* Connected to IP NUMBER (IP NUMBER) port 6443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* NSS error -5961
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I don't know what I am missing in the setup.  By convention, the other applications that connect to this port connect via IP number, not hostname.

Comment: you'll need a certificate for that ip address too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name

Comment: your ssl certificate is for your hostname not your ip..change it

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan and @KoustavRay The `-k` switch should make `curl` ignore the hostname mismatch.

Comment: What happens if you try to connect with `openssl s_client`?