# LetsEncrypt SSL on IP Address

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

How to install LetsEncrypt SSL on public IP Address?

I have tried it on domains and it is working fine. But can't be able to install it on IP Address.

Comment: SSL certificates are inherently tied to a domain name, not an IP address. You could, in theory, serve it on all vhosts on a given IP, but that probably only makes sense if you have a wildcard certificate.

Comment: @Vatine, in principle, [it is possible to obtain a certificate for an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2043645/).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Let's Encrypt issues domain-validated certificates. The certificates must be attached to at least a domain name.

Moreover, [Let's Encrypt policy is to not issue SSL certificates for IP addresses](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificate-for-public-ip-without-domain-name/6082?u=weppos), therefore you won't be able to use the certificate to a server that is reachable only through its IP address.

Technically, you can install it. But when connecting to the IP address, the clients will display a certificate name mismatch error.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, SSL on IP can be implemented. During the SSL ordering process, you need to put IP instead of domain name. But as LetsEncrypt is new to market, not sure about them.

Comment: Yes, we can easy install any paid SSL to IP Address. But LetsEncrypt are not offering this service right now.

Comment: The error if you try that is : `The Let's
Encrypt certificate authority will not issue certificates for a bare IP address.`

Comment: Is there a work-around?