# Apache virtual host redirect issue

Tags: apache

I'm trying to host a site on my server(vultr) The site is live and I have a domain name from Namecheap pointed to it. I have used Let's Encrypt and have https for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com.

I also have it set so when you enter the ip like: http://111.222.33.444 it directs to the secured domain name. So everything up to this point works just as I expected, but then I encounter this problem: if someone enters https:///111.222.33.444 the untrusted website warning page comes up. I want this to also just direct to https://example.com.

I have .conf files for http and https. I probably also have too much rubbish in these files, so probably need to write these more efficiently.

home.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/home
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 111.222.33.444
        ServerAlias 111.222.33.444
        UseCanonicalName Off
        Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
        #ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry, direct IP access not allowed."
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

home-le-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/home
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName 111.222.33.444
   ServerAlias 111.222.33.444
   UseCanonicalName Off
   Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com"
   ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry, direct IP access not allowed."
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   SSLEngine on
   <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
   </FilesMatch>
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
   </Directory>
   SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem             
   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: As for "...any suggestions..." that's not what this site is for. There is a sister site at https://codereview.stackexchange.com but I don't know if this would be on-topic there.

Comment: my issue is different than what that post refers to. how do other sites protect themselves? Im just trying to protect my site so that if a user enters the ip the end result is the secured domain, I dont want a ssl certificate for the ip since i dont want the ip to be a way to access the site, I want it to redirect.

Comment: Comment expanded to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Apache configuration; an SSL certificate has to be valid for the URL you request. From the point of view of the browser, following a redirect response requires exactly the same trust in the certificate as rendering some content from the response.

From a security point of view, imagine I intercept your wi-fi signal and respond to a request for https://www.facebook.com with a redirect to https://www.my-evil-hacking-site.com (or something less obvious). If the browser follows that redirect without checking the certificate I present, I've successfully defeated the security provided by the certficate validation.

From a technical point of view, note that a TLS (formerly known as SSL) connection is negotiated *before any HTTP request is made at all*, and the redirect you're trying to issue is an HTTP response. There actually had to be an extension to TLS to allow the requested hostname to be transmitted as part of that negotiation, to allow for multiple virtual hosts on one IP address. If the browser rejects the certificate the server offers at this stage, it will never send an HTTP request for you to respond to.

So, as far as the browser is concerned, you need to present a certificate which is valid for https:///111.222.33.444. See: [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name) to which the answer is "Yes, but it's rare". Also note that [Let's Encrypt do not issue such certificates.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303344/letsencrypt-ssl-on-ip-address)

The reason it's rare is that there's generally no reason for anyone to try to browse to https:///111.222.33.444 in the first place. Redirects are mostly just a convenience to the user, and certificate checks are about protecting the user, not protecting the server; so just leaving it as a certificate error is generally fine.