# Self sign certificate with different server

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, self-signed

I have generated a self sign ssl certificate for my server, can I use the same certificate with different server?

Comment: If you are creating and using self-signed certificates, then you may as well create a new one for the new host. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well SSL certificates are usually used to protect domains and not ip addresses. You can try to generate a SSL certificate for an ip address.

You can enter the ip address in the common names field when generating Certificate Signing Request (CSR). But the same SSL certificate may not work on another ip address. A similar issue was discussed on: [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name)

You can create your own host name and enter it in the hosts file of your operating system. Then you will have to create one self signed SSL certificate for this domain. You can use this SSL certificate on as many servers as you want.

If your server has a public ip address, then you should consider purchasing a domain from a domain provider such as GoDaddy.

Comment: Thats so helpful, thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same certificate for as many servers as your want, until your domain name matches the common name in the certificate.
Note that it will still be untrusted for every client as it is not signed by a CA.

Comment: If i dont have domain name , can I use an IP instead?

Comment: No, that will not work. You will need a domain name.