# mosquitto_sub Error:A TLS error occurred but is ok whit --insecure

Tags: linux, ssl, mosquitto

I'm building a mqtt server. I used the mosquitto with the TLS on the server as a broker.

I encountered this problem:
I created the `ca.crt`, server certificate, server key, client certificate, client key via [`generate-CA.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owntracks/tools/master/TLS/generate-CA.sh)

I can connect the broker and publish and subscribe msg via MQTT.fx, but when I tried to connect the broker with the mosquitto_sub, it came out `Error:A TLS error occurred` on the client PC(ubuntu), at the same time, the server prints

```
New connection from xx.xx.xx.xx on port 8883.
Openssl Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Openssl Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure
```

my command used is:

`mosquitto_sub -p 8883 -i test -t mqtt -h 150.xx.xx.xx --cafile ca.crt --cert xx.crt --key xx.key` in which, the `150.xx.xx.xx` is the IP of my broker.

when I used the option `--insecure` with the command above, the problem disappeared.
so I　think it is the server hostname which leads to this problem.
In the mosquitto_sub command the option `-h` specifies the hostname, but i need to use this parameter to point to the IP address of my broker, so how could i specify the hostname of my server??

Answer (score 0):

Old question but perhaps this might help someone:

If the `--insecure` option makes it work, you have a certificate problem. What hostname did you set whilst signing the certificate? What does `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 150.xx.xx.xx:8883` say?

Related: although it should be possible to use SSL certs for your servers using *public* IP addresses (see [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name)), I'd recommend *not* doing this and just using DNS, even if this means `server.localdomain` and/or editing your `/etc/hosts` file if necessary.