# TLS / SSL issue while forwarding domain to Golang web service on root server

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

Would be glad if someone could help me with my specific problem or even lead me to the right or better direction. I will now explain my problem:

I have a domain at a hoster and I can also assign a SSL certificate to it.

Instead of uploading my web content through the FTP to the web server which is included (I bet there is some Apache running in the background), I would rather use a golang web server which I can deploy on a root server.

The root server I have, has a static IP.

If I enable my SSL certificate and go to the domain everything is fine (secured symbol appears).

But I do want now all the traffic which comes to my domain to be forwarded to my root server web service which is only represented by the static IP.

So going in the menu, I can then redirect the traffic from e.g. "my-fancy-domain.com" to the static IP by saying: forward to e.g. https://123.123.123.123

But obviously you will then get a browser warning which says that the server could be hijacked by a MITM attack since I have issued the cert by myself.

How can I solve this issue to have domains pointing over a secured service to my static IP Webserver?

Comment: Assuming this is a public IPaddress, dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731321/is-it-possible-to-get-ssl-certificate-for-ipport-instead-of-a-domain-name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404386/can-i-get-an-ssl-certificate-for-an-ip-address https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68132988/how-do-i-enable-ssl-certificate-for-vps-server-ip-address .

Comment: But it appears you don't really need the 'hoster' at all. Why not just register the domain, set DNS to resolve that domain to your address, and (get and) use a cert for the domain name like everybody else?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you. It took a bit of effort but finally I was able to set the DNS A record pointing to the IP of my server. After a few problems with let's encrypt + adjusting my golang server it worked. Thank you for the hints.