# IP with HTTPS gives "Your connection is not private" [Nginx/Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, redirect, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I am using NGINX for 301 redirects on Ubuntu and reverse proxy for my Web Application and aim is to redirect traffic to non-www url such as `https://mywebapplication.com`.

So with my current config for NGINX Conf File:

```
mywebapplication.com -> https://mywebapplication.com
www.mywebapplication.com -> https://mywebapplication.com
http://mywebapplication.com -> https://mywebapplication.com
http://www.mywebapplication.com -> https://mywebapplication.com
123.456.789.123 -> https://mywebapplication.com
http://123.456.789.123 -> https://mywebapplication.com
```

Works fine but when IP with HTTPS is provided in the URL, I get "Your connection is not private."

> https://123.456.789.123 -> Your connection is not private

Here's my NGINX Conf.

```
server {
    listen 123.456.789.123:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:4000/";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }
}

server {
    listen 123.456.789.123:80;
    server_name  123.456.789.123 123.456.789.123:4000;
    return       301 https://mywebapplication.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 http2;
    listen [::]:80 http2;
    server_name  mywebapplication.com www.mywebapplication.com;
    return       301 https://mywebapplication.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.mywebapplication.com;
    return       301 https://mywebapplication.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name mywebapplication.com;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

How can I handle IP with HTTPS to a successful 301 redirection?

> https://123.456.789.123 -> https://mywebapplication.com

Thanking you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you would need a TLS certificate for a bare IP address. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name), such certificates are really rare. When you open the certificate in the browser (when it says "Your connection is not secure"), you see that the certificate is only valid for `mywebapplication.com` and not for `123.456.789.123`.

A signed certificate for an IP address does not make much sense. Such a certificate would assure the user that he is connected to `123.456.789.123`. However, this is not really telling. Without DNS, the user does not know, who is behind this IP. A user wants to be assured that he is connected to service identified by a domain name, e.g.`mywebapplication.com`, and doesn't really care if the ip is `123.456.789.123` or `321.654.987.321`.

I don't think this is a large issue. You can see for yourself, if large web sites have a certificate for their bare IP: (please note that the servers behind the IPs below might host something else in the future):

- Google: https://172.217.18.14/
- Facebook: https://185.60.216.35/
- Github: https://192.30.253.112/

None of these sites have certificates for their bare IP. (Some have redirects for HTTP in place)