# Is https needed for getUserMedia when using a Webview on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview, getusermedia

Browsers enforce `https` when using `getUserMedia`. I am working on a web app made to be used on a local network rather than actually connecting to the internet so going for a typical TLS cert won't really work. If I use a webview in an iOS app, would `getUserMedia` work when pointing the view at an IP address serving a website?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2043617/3151675

Comment: @TamásSengel Yeah I thought about doing this. I simplified my question a bit - I might be in a place with no router so I'd have people connect via bluetooth. (See https://superuser.com/questions/1405531/how-does-expressjs-serve-website-over-bluetooth-without-internet) so I suppose I can buy a cert for something like `macname.local` rather than `something.com`

Comment: If the answer to my question is yes, I can avoid buying a cert to accomplish what I want, with the help of an app :) I might have to jump into some mobile tests - I never programmed mobile apps before hence my high level question about something random.