# Cloudflare blocks mixed content from Wordpress deployment

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cloudflare

I have just started to migrate from a managed Wordpress instance on GoDaddy to a self-managed digital ocean instance. Whilst doing so I also took the decision to migrate my DNS from GoDaddy to Cloudflare. I also took the liberty to install an SSL cert via LetsEncrypt onto the digital ocean instance.

Accessing the website via HTTP is as expected however, when using HTTPS some assets are blocked as they're not loaded via HTTPS.

[image]

I have attempted to enable HTTPS rewrites via the Cloudflare dash but without any joy. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: You can try this plugin :-) [https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) Just install and activate it.

Answer (score 0):

The resource the site is trying to access is not from the same origin (http://165.22.112.133) as the requested page. Since you [don't want to create a certificate for an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name) you need to perform the following steps: Go to your WordPress settings and make sure, that the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) are both set https://richpayne.me/

If that doesn't work make sure that you haven't hardcoded http://165.22.112.133 anywhere in your theme.