# REST API over https in Google Compute Engine

Tags: https, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Does anyone know how to easily setup https for a rest api in google compute engine ? I have currently a static ip and the api works over http but in the browser when I call it I get mixed content error because the client is server over https (firebase hosting)

Is it possible to setup https with only a static ip (and not a domain name) ?

-Jani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to setup https with only a static ip (and not a domain
>   name) ?

Yes, it is possible, but since 2016 you cannot purchase an SSL certificate with a public IP address. You can use a self-signed certificate but you will have even more browser issues. Not recommended.

**Possible Options:**

1. Use your domain name (or purchase one) and use Let's Encrypt for SSL which is free and is one of your better options.
2. Use a different service such as Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, Firebase or App Engine which offers SSL and does not require a domain name that you own as you can use Google's endpoint.
3. Attach a Google Load Balancer in front of your Compute Engine instance and configure a front end with a Google Managed SSL certificate. However, this will require a domain name.

If you do not want to use your own domain name, then option #2 is your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

To setup https for a rest api in google compute engine:

1- You have to buy a domain
2- You have to buy an SSL certificate
3- create a load balance resource in Google Cloud to which I assign the domain and the certificate
4- You can install the certificate to the server directly

If you want to use https over IP instead of domain, please follow click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name)