# How Can Access Camara And Mic Globally in Agora.io

Tags: webrtc, angular7, agora.io

I am using `Angular 7` with `Angora.Io`, My problem is when I run my Angular project locally then I successfully get access to my camera and microphone but when I try to run globally like "192.105.2.448" then I don't get access to my camera and microphone and an error like this is thrown. Please help me!

```
join(): void {

    this.client.setClientRole('host');
    this.localStream = this.agoraService.createStream({ streamID: this.uid, audio: true, video: true, screen: false });
    this.localStream.setVideoProfile('720p_3');
    this.assignLocalStreamHandlers();
    this.init();
    this.client.join(null , this.channel.value, this.uid);
}

publish(): void {

    this.liveplay = true;
    this.client.publish(this.localStream, err =>   console.log('Publish local stream error: ' + err));  }

protected init(): void {

    this.localStream.init(
        () => {
            // The user has granted access to the camera and mic.
            console.log('getUserMedia successfully' , this.localStream);
            this.localStream.play('agora_local');
            this.connected = true;
        },
        err => console.log('getUserMedia failed', err)
    );
}


private assignLocalStreamHandlers(): void {

    console.log('==========>>>>>>>2 ');
    this.localStream.on(StreamEvent.MediaAccessAllowed, () => {
        console.log('accessAllowed --->>> ', this.localStream);
    });
    // The user has denied access to the camera and mic.
        this.localStream.on(StreamEvent.MediaAccessDenied, () => {
        console.log('accessDenied');
    });
}
```

> 11:35:01:76 Agora-SDK [ERROR]: [3]  Media access NOT_SUPPORTED: Only secure origins are allowed
>
> [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. It seems that there is no research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is not an issue unique to Agora's SDK but is the expected behavior of any web browser. 
In order to access `Camera` and `Microphone` permissions all browsers require you to use a secure connection (read: `HTTPS`) and will block access to any websites that are not accessed with a secure connection.

Browsers do have one special feature which has white-listed `localhost` so that any projects being run locally using `localhost` will be allowed to access device permissions. This is why your project works *"locally"* but not *"globally"*.

For you to be able to test your project *"globally"* then you will need to use a domain with an ssl certificate so that you see `https` in the url. While possible to use `HTTPS` with an IP address it is not common nor recommended ([Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name))

One option *(that I like to use)* for testing is NGROK (https://ngrok.com), they offer a tunneling service that creates a "tunnel out" from your machine and provides an `https` url that enables you to test projects that are running on your local machine.

> **disclaimer:** I am in no way affiliated with NGROK, this is a tool I that I find helpful and choose to use while testing my code, to work around the restrictions imposed by browsers without deploying my work to a remote server.

Answer (score -1):

I am not into Angular but since agora provide some api regarding custom Audio/Video sources. you can check https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/custom_video_web?platform=Web