# SSL for backend server without domain

Tags: spring-boot, security, backend, lets-encrypt

I have a vps, where my spring boot backend is running on. The frontend is a mobile app built with the ionic framework.

The backend is built this way: in the front there is an so called resource server, which is an graphql server, which redirects the requests to rest microservices which are behind the resource server. Every microservice has is own task, which he's responsible for. (e.g. an fileupload-server which uploads/downloads files to a database). The whole application, including the frontend is secured by an keycloak instance, which is running as an docker container like the whole application, except the frontend.

Now my questions is, we dont have a domain and for some reason they wont buy one, but we wont to secure the communications over ssl/lets encrypt. But lets encrypt isn't able to create ssl certificates for ip adresses. So finnaly my question is: do you guys, know a solution to my problem which fits?

So far,
Daniel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name  check this

Comment: View the answet under the marked as confirmed answer which have 58 votes, it have some links for help..