# Issue with making a http request to a docker

Tags: java, android, apache, docker, ssl

I use Apache for HTTP requests for my android app but I got a little problem that I can't find a solution. I'm able to do a get request to a website URL like google or stuff like that but I can't do the same for my server on a Docker with an Url like "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api..."
I get this error:

System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx> doesn't contain CN or DNS subjectAlt

Does anyone have a solution for me in order to be able to make requests to my docker?
thanks,

Comment: `with a DNS like "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api..."` That is no DNS but an url. Further you should not call a dns service if you use an ip address if that is what you do. Please explain better.

Comment: Can you use a browser on your pc? And a browser on your Android device?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Actually I want to make an HTTP request to my API on a docker in order to get a token from Cookies. URLs of the API looks like "https://192.168.xxx.xxx/api/..." but I tried to make a request with my code and I get the error: "System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx> doesn't contain CN or DNS subjectAlt" and I can't find a solution to solve it. Sorry about my bad explanation I'm very not at ease with HTTP stuff.

Comment: And i have no idea what you mean by Docker.

Comment: Your issue is that you'ar acessing your server in https using its IP address. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name