# Aws - acm certificate bind to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an application and api  running/hosted in  same aws ec2 instance . I have enabled ssl cert using acm via load balancer for application domain . However , my api is exposing via ec2 public ip i.e http://ec2ip. In such scenario how can I bind ssl cert in IP address i.e https://ec2ip ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name)

Comment: Why not also send the API requests through the load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

You ideally [don't want to have a public IP on your load-balanced EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/). You can achieve this by placing the EC2s in a private subnet. This will need [bastion server](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/linux-bastion/) in order to SSH though.

If you absolutely want HTTPS on an IP address, [this SO page is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name). If you do set that up, make sure that it is an elastic IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you have load balance you shouldn't directly access your instance using public IP. As per AWS documentation you shouldn't even have a public IP address for your instance.

someday if you run security assessment to your aws environment, *AWS Foundational Security Best Practices v1.0.0* will be failed because of public IP.

> EC2 instances should not have a public IPv4 address

This all about security concerns. Typically, only a Load Balancer is exposed to the Internet.

[Back to Basics: Protecting Your Network in the Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JIyApfH630)