# How to add ssl certicate in kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I just created a new kubernetes with one node poll in Digitalocean. I've installed nginx service in that pool. Now I can access that node pool using http://ip-address:port number. Now I need to add ssl certificate for this ip address. Is that possible? How can I add certificate for this ip address

Comment: Assigning ssl/tls certificate for an IP address seems to be possible (one of the [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)). However if you just want to play around, it's much easier to sign your own certificate and perform test you want to ([securing-the-service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#securing-the-service)) Do you need to have IP address exposed or what is the goal?

Answer (score 0):

The standard tool for LetsEncrypt on Kubernetes is cert-manager, https://cert-manager.io/docs/. You can also purchase a cert (or make a self-signed one, but that probably doesn't help) and configure it manually a la https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets.

Comment: with the help of a tutorial I've added load balencer and add a subdomain in it. The ssl works perfectly but it show "502 Bad Gateway" error code. The tutorial I've used is https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/how-to/configure-load-balancers/#ssl-annotation