# can I have ssl certificate in AWS without domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services

for learning purpose I need to have ssL certificate in my ec2 Instance without a domain name can I do that in AWS?
if I can how?

Comment: You can have whatever you want in your ec2 instance but AWS will obviously not issue you a certificate for a domain you do not own. But you can self-sign whatever you want and use it inside your instance.

Comment: It's pretty simple to generate your own certificate and have your https server serve that certificate. The "issue" is that your certificate won't be recognized by any browser.

Comment: @luk2302 I want the certificate in the IP address can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name

Answer (score 0):

For Learning purposes: No

For Real Life / Production purposes: Yes

some providers offer IP address SSL certificate, but these are for public IPs and not really something for Learning

https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/general-ssl/securing-public-ip-address-ssl-certificates