# ESP32 MQTT with TLS not working with NATS MQTT

Tags: c++, ssl, mqtt, esp32, nats.io

Hi i have a project about connect ESP32 to NATS via MQTT

After I try `--insecurity` it work normally.

But when I add TLS it doesn't work in my ESP32, i also try with Python it work normally with my self-signed SSL certificate.

I already find solution from here but it not work: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/5021

My idea code get from here: https://github.com/debsahu/ESP-MQTT-AWS-IoT-Core/blob/master/Arduino/PubSubClient/PubSubClient.ino

Is MQTT TLS in ESP32 not work with self-signed cert or I done something wrong ?

Cert TLS:

```
    "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    "MIID8TCCAtmgAwIBAgIUfceZXKK1JIqHi57rc98EBmJoy1kwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n"
    "BQAwgYcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlZOMRAwDgYDVQQIDAd2aWV0bmFtMRAwDgYDVQQHDAd2\n"
    "aWV0bmFtMQ4wDAYDVQQKDAVwZWNvbTENMAsGA1UECwwEdGVzdDENMAsGA1UEAwwE\n"
    "bXF0dDEmMCQGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYXY3B0cHJpY2UxMjNAb3V0bG9vay5jb20wHhcN\n"
    "MjIxMTAzMDgxMDEzWhcNMjMxMTAzMDgxMDEzWjCBhzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVk4xEDAO\n"
    "BgNVBAgMB3ZpZXRuYW0xEDAOBgNVBAcMB3ZpZXRuYW0xDjAMBgNVBAoMBXBlY29t\n"
    "MQ0wCwYDVQQLDAR0ZXN0MQ0wCwYDVQQDDARtcXR0MSYwJAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhdj\n"
    "cHRwcmljZTEyM0BvdXRsb29rLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCC\n"
    "AQoCggEBALRTuKn8m1QuFJI3THb2rkEiKPHD/cdRs/E1Vb96GIBSy4D/s8vJ2OWd\n"
    "GHlbLK557OpAH7JrRg6tVEVVr3293u8imwDIcNyOHlBYWSO/DBKGXsoCbOL1u6Gd\n"
    "zAn/G+96eX3RUIHRbBF/rE6DZS5Y1Piq7FwdaReHSZhMPB+UMB4xUEC3pC6CzqFt\n"
    "xjudk9zT5VpR60XiJAls3YtYpUu4zRZUw2Sb1ZsPmT555QFYbOcF4XlC82MVi/o3\n"
    "M91LJ8DyiOvNWxuioIT2frEyIXaTleug3Ev0ALiu8ug9/v/zTWZWq3KA98HZJcm+\n"
    "Hr8dChlMewpMpabEi1e0twlzTPw9QyMCAwEAAaNTMFEwHQYDVR0OBBYEFE3SQ0F5\n"
    "yzsBkHUcFp/KucgyGHpWMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFE3SQ0F5yzsBkHUcFp/KucgyGHpW\n"
    "MA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAC+pjnAd9c71DfCv\n"
    "RUMvYg93mraaqtoEw22ggtT9AfIZfI+o8L5Nxk5us+9k9IBEP4hi6DHtnFxqfFt8\n"
    "YkzNNDMTDvLfg/1INUwg8yBYS9Z2+puoPlPTvaxOJiuz2+DkYV/LnUdTolKPqYrO\n"
    "IBIbmwMNz0Bqn1XZ7Mjx9U7p+A2N/87NGl3fo0I0tWBRSGXFZB7IYipgCPQG5Eb+\n"
    "ZL9vrgFuNJhAVALvDfwKxCX6VdyNpthAMA7cmra+s0/weZsfQLyU2TtnsIg0uoq0\n"
    "L4sTpL6Q7Fr4UpOJrezNx/kuHHxBBKhJtlz4Tcaw/OKu/h2g5jjHFT9yN86KUxSY\n"
    "PDH47kk=\n"
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

// You can use x.509 client certificates if you want
const char *test_client_key =
    "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    "MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAllaf/na5h3yDr2zoYsYGGqt/d93/AAUTculGTXdGGbRwyHue\n"
    "b0BaMeX+ht9siZ82iuaZ/5mJ/kq8WVwlrkegOAvU7SQDoALPM7VLMLSMbnn2Wqog\n"
    "WE48TkWU0WddtTFHVDGLX8zMC1TQ1VKyVzp2QtCW9RPJNun9CVJSoZ34uM5hBL1f\n"
    "7MY7t/QsDYi14UtULDsSnVz+tDLiPrBkZOPEVhopCH1gvljcDTcICfawyK5nlCKc\n"
    "AnUWTHEUzf89WCJkPNk1W3LhscGKfx2bV8XVv+izg2zMLec5aYM/LrJg6HpJzgQJ\n"
    "IKBt1tWQkxRvO7LO3znSp8A9DXotvr0MkIqcjQIDAQABAoIBAEMAaF3oW9deTvIn\n"
    "/4nF54KLXEv3zGYd3QUhogt0VPGv0XQIZBwA+jGy5zUE7kKHiq9tBsU7kJycgkTx\n"
    "JHn/whA4dbUaj+MIXYAWFGSoks3J3Vma6L9yXr4jlKefAcx3IesMCamwhF+odUod\n"
    "iQ4HKB2vCRhAsTSgI/27isgst2TlJsGMf7ED2N1jae8ZyOITi2g0F1edRYBwgSHq\n"
    "MZvccZh/IpuTOPEVxuITYyQT9WF0TCz7cK4wCP5dACQQB6Or8l2xiUf9dx3I7kwR\n"
    "7wvivI+jAoxR/peOXx2o0bHPcqh41rbhbE00XOcIReGoyLsRDvicw3hgFe6UxcEm\n"
    "PlpFzaECgYEAyBPpzK3x0iXj66iO6erXzciN5cXF8IZhC7xcCgGOpnjgrMV3FUNv\n"
    "L0Qu8zUlTJHfWpITCZawPpbNMaNShykLU6NqxUPXGtaH/xVUZm9VbkRwBQoQKg+w\n"
    "x2+hAWTGu4rWtSaWMHJuwI0SYyopvJtBgDO8PkmzDG24RQuRVBSE+ycCgYEAwFu6\n"
    "QHVHvVm4ri1FCIK313uXTWoYhKDCm8ygDKT608bHzBoqOcXPT5mcr3IZmZitsg3Y\n"
    "DyVvPGmmbLp8FmxXcz2c71e1Bupeq9V8HrMiSgMVPEIRuNKVC7WE/Ymuvpvfd+h/\n"
    "RyDCu2wTI4GcJRhmAB+SpjPPOH0qaqV2eHZgSysCgYAO5eyy4QDwtQGTuqlpoaMQ\n"
    "H67xPRjQIDF5vjzcQeFtY/LW6p1DaBIPYvRcB8kPOo13IQlp3V6iSnhdCdxLVDMT\n"
    "t0dsCPErfm4CAISYXBHwdAgjV+x8NU7kittiTy69KEl0k7r7QIoerGKCH9GbybPG\n"
    "6BNMUBCVDFZ8TbA0opKEYQKBgEl0/fxNjTbXA3qoWPt2B8SnMtFiWbiUN50NmHUb\n"
    "r5meCIB94XAshQ2NyNMLDJGmR3Z+aOrnzcHRSresw2RAvWiJt9uCr+PTLpIKNZr3\n"
    "p3mCEeLwDBp7eGV/TSkRIgUyOzVsOOatsQ+nputhPILB/XnAlN0ZXeHhkoglZcd8\n"
    "1Sr/AoGAU7nlyAMQNd/tckwPTnM++0ewrFvwrfpS7f2dhcYbIhfqQ3I03Gwzjkkg\n"
    "G85uzTg/8iO4oxPRjqPvc7JaoDDmGY/efQvjR+FdwDOuy+XZPImZIgGjl0yvAMFU\n"
    "6azU+OxtwV+Yyfad4rGxaXZsqOIs18to94t2kjI0t8ur/4Q7C5w=\n"
    "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"; // to verify the client
const char *test_client_cert =
    "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    "MIIDnjCCAoYCFBRQlTP3aMzr8YtFlYoaVtrPIN6xMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGH\n"
    "MQswCQYDVQQGEwJWTjEQMA4GA1UECAwHdmlldG5hbTEQMA4GA1UEBwwHdmlldG5h\n"
    "bTEOMAwGA1UECgwFcGVjb20xDTALBgNVBAsMBHRlc3QxDTALBgNVBAMMBG1xdHQx\n"
    "JjAkBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWF2NwdHByaWNlMTIzQG91dGxvb2suY29tMB4XDTIyMTEw\n"
    "MzA4MTMzMVoXDTIzMDIxMTA4MTMzMVowgY4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlZOMRAwDgYDVQQI\n"
    "DAd2aWV0bmFtMRAwDgYDVQQHDAd2aWV0bmFtMQ4wDAYDVQQKDAVwZWNvbTENMAsG\n"
    "A1UECwwEdGVzdDETMBEGA1UEAwwKbXF0dGNsaWVudDEnMCUGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYY\n"
    "Y3B0cHJpY2VAMTIzQG91dGxvb2suY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8A\n"
    "MIIBCgKCAQEAllaf/na5h3yDr2zoYsYGGqt/d93/AAUTculGTXdGGbRwyHueb0Ba\n"
    "MeX+ht9siZ82iuaZ/5mJ/kq8WVwlrkegOAvU7SQDoALPM7VLMLSMbnn2WqogWE48\n"
    "TkWU0WddtTFHVDGLX8zMC1TQ1VKyVzp2QtCW9RPJNun9CVJSoZ34uM5hBL1f7MY7\n"
    "t/QsDYi14UtULDsSnVz+tDLiPrBkZOPEVhopCH1gvljcDTcICfawyK5nlCKcAnUW\n"
    "THEUzf89WCJkPNk1W3LhscGKfx2bV8XVv+izg2zMLec5aYM/LrJg6HpJzgQJIKBt\n"
    "1tWQkxRvO7LO3znSp8A9DXotvr0MkIqcjQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IB\n"
    "AQCF33dWLyL/QJKDBNtKc6WwmOn97u74jkIYdgRHgQwNvrmLHRgZPb6Bhzy5KAIY\n"
    "qJcPA6Cn/m4utUWjAXRPj9zDT5xyeC843R22KQASjmPBnEyfDZuXmUPjjNJUSUx6\n"
    "JGk/bwPQDLT2ID+vl3OInm4ypgwbGaqlhn41m0F2smanuZUFgEmN5+tJpkwK/tVP\n"
    "IYHJ5HPnFqDFs84Fp12HU2QcqbOUEZ/d77Yw/dfb20cvgW2xkHKEAhz7d9EpD4ov\n"
    "S5ZnelKxvqlVzI2v2I6MJkRdeP2IfYofNfRo2s7S5u+h/2SQu1MbbarS/jd32Ldz\n"
    "14EVvDj+sCF2g7skdJ3kYCPI\n"
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"; // to verify the client
```

Server config:

```
listen:0.0.0.0:4222

jetstream:{
    max_memory_store: 1073741824
    max_file_store: 1073741824
}

mqtt {
    # Specify a host and port to listen for websocket connections
    #
    listen: "0.0.0.0:8883"
    # It can also be configured with individual parameters,
    # namely host and port.
    #
    # host: "hostname"
    # port: 1883

    # TLS configuration.
    tls {
        cert_file: /etc/tls/mqtt/broker/broker.crt
        key_file: /etc/tls/mqtt/broker/broker.key
        ca_file: /etc/tls/mqtt/ca/ca.crt
        verify: true
        timeout: 2.0
        # verify_and_map: true
    }

    # no_auth_user: "my_username_for_apps_not_providing_credentials"

    # authorization {
    #     # username: "my_user_name"
    #     # password: "my_password"
    #     # token: "my_token"
    #     # timeout: 2.0
    # }
    ack_wait: "1m"
    max_ack_pending: 100
}

tls:{
    cert_file: /etc/tls/natsio/server-cert.pem
    key_file: /etc/tls/natsio/server-key.pem
    ca_file: /etc/tls/natsio/ca-cert.pem
}

http_port: 8222


# system_account: AAOQAS43OSVDMF3ERYSNL3GMGZRD7GILDGDET6R52NFZKEWJOTTVNYZ4

# resolver: {
#     type: full
#     dir: './jwt'
#     allow_delete: false
#     interval: "2m"
#     limit: 1000
# }
```

Logs from NATS server:

```
test-nats-dev-1  | [1] 2022/11/03 10:29:32.794114 [ERR] 192.168.1.14:57479 - mid:699 - TLS handshake error: remote error: tls: bad certificate
test-nats-dev-1  | [1] 2022/11/03 10:29:37.989099 [ERR] 192.168.1.14:57480 - mid:700 - TLS handshake error: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

ESP32 logs:

```
Attempting MQTT connection...[2959556][E][ssl_client.cpp:37] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():276]: (-9984) X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
[2959559][E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:135] connect(): start_ssl_client: -9984
failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...[2964762][E][ssl_client.cpp:37] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():276]: (-9984) X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
[2964765][E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:135] connect(): start_ssl_client: -9984
failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...[2976298][E][ssl_client.cpp:37] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():276]: (-9984) X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
[2976301][E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:135] connect(): start_ssl_client: -9984
failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem is my cert is using domain for certification and I using IP for connection. That is make it not working.

After change to using domain in connection it works normally.

Domain TLS: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/what-is-domain-tls/

IP TLS: [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name)