# Add an IP address as Alternate Name to a Certificate

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I wanted to create a self signed certificated using the cert enroll library in C#.

I'm trying to add alternate subject names to the certificate. With DNS and URL this works fine, but if I try to use a IP address it throws an "Value does not fall into the expected range" exception.

Heres the code:

```
CX509CertificateRequestCertificate certificate = new();
...
// Add alternate names
CX509ExtensionAlternativeNamesClass alternateNames = new();
CAlternativeNamesClass cAlternativeNames = new();
foreach (CertificateAlias alias in settings.Aliases)
{
    CAlternativeNameClass cAlternativeName = new();
    // alias.Name is "100.120.140.160" in my test case
    cAlternativeName.InitializeFromString(alias.Type.ToAlternativeNameType(), alias.Name);
    cAlternativeNames.Add(cAlternativeName);
}
alternateNames.InitializeEncode(cAlternativeNames);
certificate.X509Extensions.Add(alternateNames as CX509Extension);

certificate.Encode();
...
```

"settings.Aliases" is just my stored list of desired alternate names. A "CertificateAlias" just contains the type of alternate name (via enum mapping) and the actual name, nothing fancy here.

I also tried the approach with using InitializeFromRawData like this
`cAlternativeName.InitializeFromRawData(AlternativeNameType.XCN_CERT_ALT_NAME_IP_ADDRESS, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("100.120.140.160")));`
but then it appears as Base64 in the certificate alternate names details which can't be correct.

Additionally I just tried
`cAlternativeName.InitializeFromRawData(AlternativeNameType.XCN_CERT_ALT_NAME_IP_ADDRESS, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, "100.120.140.160");`
but that throws an "invalid data" exception.

At this point I'm clueless. How would I include an IP address here?

Edit: This certificate is only intended to be used for the local machine.

Edit 2: I got it to work, I had to exclude the IP Address dots from the Base64 encoding and use InitializeFromRawData instead of FromString
like this:

```
List<byte> bytes = new();
string[] octets = alias.Name.Split('.');
for (int i = 0; i < octets.Length; i++)
    bytes.Add(byte.Parse(octets[i]));
cAlternativeName.InitializeFromRawData(AlternativeNameType.XCN_CERT_ALT_NAME_IP_ADDRESS, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes.ToArray()));
```

Comment: I cannot stress to you enough:  Do not go down this path if you do not understand the consequences and the details on how this works.  Your question is a duplicate and this should be closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name

Comment: @possum Maybe I'm just misreading this but that doesn't seem to answer my question nor is it a duplicate imo.  Also this process should be used for a self signed certificate only, so the local machine is the only one which should accept this (although tbf in most cases we use localhost or the hostname anyway) but I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to generate a certificate with ip subject alternative name.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


string subjectName = "CN=localhost";
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
{

    CertificateRequest req = new CertificateRequest(
        subjectName,
        rsa,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    //add subject aulternative name
    var sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
    sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.Parse("101.101.101.101"));
    req.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

    //generate certificate
    var certificate = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(50));


    var exportableCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
        certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert),
        (string)null,
        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet
        ).CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);


    // Create password for certificate protection
    var passwordForCertificateProtection = new SecureString();

    foreach (var @char in "123")
    {
        passwordForCertificateProtection.AppendChar(@char);
    }

    // Export certificate to a file.
    File.WriteAllBytes(
        "test.pfx",
        exportableCertificate.Export(
            X509ContentType.Pfx,
            passwordForCertificateProtection
        )
    );
}
```

After install
[image]

Comment: `CreateSelfSigned` already creates a certificate with a bound private key, `X509KeyStorageFlags` only matter when loading a PFX/PKCS12 blob, so they don't matter on your import into `exportableCertificate` (and you definitely don't want `PersistKeySet`).  So `var exportableCertificate = certificate;` works just as well, meaning `exportableCertificate` serves no purpose.  Oh, and `SecureString` is deprecated, don't use it :).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with the CertEnroll library I'm currently using. But I figured it out. Thanks anyway :)