# Changing ip address for a domain name - how to test if ssl will still work?

Tags: ssl, ip, ssl-certificate

I've got a domain purchased from godaddy (example.com), as well as an ssl certificate from them for that same domain. I have a single machine running a web server and a static ip, the domain from godaddy points to that static ip. The ssl cert is installed on that machine, and everything works fine.

Now I need to start hosting from a different machine, which has a different static IP address. I believe all I have to do is change the IP address for my domain in godaddy's control panel, and the ssl certificate should still be valid, even though it's a new IP address.

Is there any way to test this beforehand? Is my assumption correct that just changing the IP address in the domain record is all I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SSL certificates are (almost always) associated with domain names, not IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095780/are-ssl-certificates-bound-to-the-servers-ip-address). Assuming you have a standard configuration for your SSL cert, you're fine.

But! You want to test this beforehand. OK:

```
openssl x509 -in yourcert.crt -text -noout
```

This command will allow you to examine your certificate. In particular, look for your hostname. Mine says something like:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
    DNS:mail.cternus.net, DNS:cternus.net
```

If your hostname is in there (and your IP address is not), you're golden.