# Will change of server's IP address affect ssl certificate?

Tags: ip, ssl-certificate, rsa-key-fingerprint

I am planning to change the IP address of a server.
The server has ssl certificate installed.

Will SSL certificate be affected after the IP address changes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095780/are-ssl-certificates-bound-to-the-servers-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

SSL certificates are not bound to IP addresses. They are bound to the fully qualified domain names such as www.stackoverflow.com

So you will not have to worry about SSL cert changes, just ensuring that the new IP is bound to your domain name.