# Can I regenerate SSL certificate with different common name?

Tags: ssl, xmpp, ssl-certificate, ejabberd

I am going to use an **SSL certificate** on my chat application based on XMPP(ejabberd) which is **hosted on an IP**.

So, I will be using the IP as the common name when I am generating my SSL certificate. But the server that has everything hosted on it, refers to the IP using a hostname as **abcd.yourserver.net**.

Therefore, I am confused as to if I have to use the IP or this weird hostname while generating my SSL certificate and if in future I decide to use a domain name instead of the IP for my application, will I have to buy a new SSl certificate or can I regenerate the old one. Also, can I change the type like wilcard or single certificate?

P.S. I have never bought an SSL certificate, so forgive me if the question is newbish.

Comment: I don't think there are places that sell trusted SSL certificates for IP addresses.

Comment: I browsed stackoverflow whole morning and found many answers that said that we can get SSL certs for IP addresses.

Comment: I stand corrected, there seem to be CAs that do.

Answer (score 0):

When generating an SSL certificate for an XMPP server, you have to use the domain name of your XMPP service.

Comment: The server hosts both the XMPP and the web services used, if that changes anything?

Comment: From XMPP point of view that does not change anything. Cert has to be for the XMPP domain (not necessarily the server name).

Comment: If I am using the IP, while connecting to the XMPP server(in the client) even then do I need a domain name?

Comment: Well, you cannot really create a certificate for an IP. You need a domain name, yes.

Comment: I found some answers on stackoverflow that suggest that it can be done. One among them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095780/are-ssl-certificates-bound-to-the-servers-ip-address. So, I guess the major concern is that is it a necessity for the XMPP server itself?

Comment: Well, you can generated a self signed certificate for an IP address, but if you are planning to buy one, no certificate authority will deliver a certificate for an IP address. Moreover, it does not really make sense.