# Local network HTTPS with IP address

Tags: ssl, https

I have a small REST server running on a local network, with a bunch of client applications connected (via IP address).

I want to secure this traffic so that access tokens cannot be sniffed.

According to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095780/are-ssl-certificates-bound-to-the-servers-ip-address) I can create a self signed cert. using an IP (although not common). If i go down this route (assuming no physical access to the server box itself) is this secure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is as secure as CA-signed certificate as long as users always install the correct certificate. (Make sure the the certificate is distributed securely.)

If distributing it securely seems too much trouble, then you may see [answers here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103524/lets-encrypt-for-intranet-websites) and consider using certificate issued by letsencrypt.org if you can.